# react native google signin failed in iOS react native

Tags: ios, swift, react-native, google-signin, react-native-ios

I run the react-native upgrade to fix the play store base 64 issue. Android is working fine the only issue I am facing with iOS. React native google sing in failed when run for the build.

I have run the following commands:

- react-native-upgrade@0.59.1
- rm -rf node_modules && npm i
- Upgrade the google sdk 4.4.0 to 5.0.0 and
- cd ios && pod install && cd ..

Here are errors:

**1) No visible @interface for 'GIDSignIn' declares the selector 'signInSilently'**

```
[[GIDSignIn sharedInstance] signInSilently];
```

**2) No visible @interface for 'GIDSignIn' declares the selector 'hasAuthInKeychain'**

```
RCT_REMAP_METHOD(isSignedIn,
                 resolver:(RCTPromiseResolveBlock)resolve
                 rejecter:(RCTPromiseRejectBlock)reject)
{
  BOOL isSignedIn = [[GIDSignIn sharedInstance] hasAuthInKeychain];
  resolve([NSNumber numberWithBool:isSignedIn]);
}
```

**3) No visible @interface for 'GIDSignIn' declares the selector 'handleURL:sourceApplication:annotation:'**

```
+ (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application openURL:(NSURL *)url
  sourceApplication:(NSString *)sourceApplication annotation: (id)annotation {

  return [[GIDSignIn sharedInstance] handleURL:url
                             sourceApplication:sourceApplication
                                    annotation:annotation];
}
```

**4) Use of undeclared identifier 'kGIDSignInErrorCodeNoSignInHandlersInstalled'**

```
case kGIDSignInErrorCodeNoSignInHandlersInstalled:
```

Please let me know if anyone can help me with this...Thanks!

Comment: Have you solved the issue?

Answer (score 1):

I am not an expert and fully understand but come up with my own approach after knowing details from documentation.

Point 4 is deprecated in 5.0.0 so comment out or delete it.
Point 1 and Point 2 you need to make entry in GoogleSignIn.h file but as per documentation hasAuthInKeychain is replaced by hasPreviousSignIn and signInSilently has been replace by hasPreviousSignIn.

You can overcome the error by adding entry for signInSilently and hasAuthInKeychain to GoogleSignIn.h file.

You can refer the details in https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/ios/release.